# How can locked files be monitored on a WIN 2000 server

Tags: filesystems, system-administration, windows-server-2000, locked-files

I'm interested to know what would be the best way to monitor locked files/open file handles on a win 2000 server. I am interested in a general system report that could show locked files or handles over time (over the course of one night, for example) without having to specify which processes are to be monitored specifically.

Thanks,
Adi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,

After some research it seems that the best sysinternals tool for this purpose would be [File Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896642.aspx). While wrapping the Handle programme (as suggested here) could work, File Monitor provides a fully customizable GUI for that purpose.

File Monitor is replaced by [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) for OS versions later than WIN2000 SP4, but since I was having to monitor an earlier version, File Monitor was definitely the way to go.

Comment: Did you ever get Process Monitor working for this purpose?  I can't find a filter that shows what process is locking a directory.  For example, cmd.exe will keep a folder from being deleted but none of its events seem to relate to locking, so filtering doesn't narrow it down.  Also, I've had issues with it filling up my page file (default log location) before the night is over. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

[Sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/0e18b180-9b7a-4c49-8120-c47c5a693683.aspx) are a Windows administrator's best friend.  Perhaps you could write something that wraps the [Handle](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx) program.

Comment: @Boden - yep. That was my initial thought as well. A simple script that wraps around Handle.